# Why does the "directrix" of a conic section have that name?

Tags: terminology, conic-sections

Conic sections may be defined in terms of the "focus-directrix property", as the loci of points that satisfy a particular relationship involving a point called the focus and a line called the directrix. While the name "focus" for the point seems easily explicable, the name "directrix" for the line is less so (to me). Where did it originally come from? Is the "-trix" suffix supposed to indicate that it is feminine in some way?

Comment: This could help with your question http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConicSectionDirectrix.html

Comment: The word directrix names in latin a feminine thing (line is feminine noun in latin) that directs. The -trix works like that, and is the femine version of -tor: it indicates a feminine agent: dominatrix, or executrix, aviatrix, generatrix, and so on.

Comment: So you are saying that because "line" is a feminine noun, "director" is modified to take a feminine form, leading to "directrix"? That seems feasible, but the word for "line" isn't anywhere to be seen; only the word "director/-trix". Or am I showing my ignorance of how grammatical gender works in Latin?

Comment: It is not «feasible»: it *is* just like that —  I am not making a guess: I am telling you how it is. The line is the directrix: if it were a point it would be the director. It is not an adjective, but a noun. It is the line that *directs* the conic.

Comment: By the way, does director circle have masculine nature?

Comment: (1) I did not use the word "feasible" to insult you or call what you say into question, rather it reflects that I don't fully understand your explanation yet. Besides which, I don't necessarily trust that what you say is accurate, because you are a more-or-less anonymous name on the internet; I don't know you, nor do I know how much weight I should give to your statements on Latin.

Comment: (2) As I said, I don't understand how the object referred to by the noun "director/-trix" modifies the gender of that noun. I had thought that in languages with grammatical gender, it is the word that confers gender, not the referent of the word; hence my confusion over how the object's being a "line" still confers femininity when the word "line" is absent. Perhaps you could add an answer and include a brief explanation of this, or a link to a relevant explanation on how Latin grammar pertains to this.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the name comes from the fact that the directrix is a fixed line, thus specifying a fixed direction.

According to merriam-webster's etymology: directrix is the ["feminine of Late Latin director"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/directrix).

I think directrix is a late Latin translation of the ancient greek work "διευθετούσα" -used by [Pappus of Alexandria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pappus_of_Alexandria) who lived during the hellenistic period- which is a feminine participle meaning smt like "the one settling the thing". Maybe [this](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/focus-directrix-hisotry.4761/) discussion on PhysicsForums might be of interest in tracing the origins of the term directrix.

Answer (score 2):

In a circle, locus of point of intersection of perpendicular tangents is the director circle.
In a parabola, locus of point of intersection of perpendicular tangents is a line- the directrix (maybe this is why its called so)

Answer (score 1):

A not-entirely-useful entry from the ["Earliest Known Uses of Some of the Words of Mathematics"](http://jeff560.tripod.com/mathword.html) pages:

> According to the DSB, Jan de Witt (1625-1672) "is credited with introducing the term 'directrix' for the parabola, but it is clear from his derivation that he does not use the term for the fixed line of our focus-directrix definition."

DSB = *The Dictionary of Scientific Biography*. C. C. Gillispie (editor in chief) New York : Charles Scribner’s Sons, 1970-1980.